# What are the best problem books on abstract algebra and linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, reference-request

What are the best undergraduate problem books on abstract algebra and linear algebra?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what level the books are at (e.g undergraduate vs graduate) and what you consider "best".

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "problem books"?  One of those "1000 Worked Exercises in ..." style books or a book with an available solutions manual or just a book with interesting exercises or ...?

Comment: Follow up on the names Hungerford and Axler.  Best of luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

I like Michael Artin's blue [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132413779). He gives you plenty of linear algebra but mostly focuses on group theory and beyond. The book is very accessible early on - personally, it helped me to be able to read other algebra books, like Hungerford. If nothing else, chapters 2 and 6 on group theory are worth a quick read, especially if you're just getting started with abstract algebra.  Artin is one of the more skillful proof writers I have come across, and reading his book changed the way I thought about mathematics in that the proof itself, and the style of the proof, became much more important.